# Undefined variable error exception in view

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, undefined-variable

Controller method

```
 public function create(Request $request )
{
   $client_id = $request->input('client_name');
   //$userid = \Auth::user()->id;
   $invoice_id = Invoice::create([
    //'userid'=>$userid,
    'clientid'=>$client_id,
    ])->id;

    return redirect('invoice/create/'.$invoice_id);
}
```

View Where I'm getting an error

```
  @if($invoice_product->product_qty!=null)
       value="{{$invoice_product->product_qty}}"
  @endif
```

Model

```
  namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class InvoiceProducts extends Model
{
protected $fillable = ['invoice_id'];
}
```

and the error Undefined variable: invoice_product (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\cs\resources\views\invoice\create.blade.php)

Comment: is there any way to pass model object to the redirect()

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'with'

> return redirect('invoice/create/'.$invoice_id)->with($invoice_id);

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to inject variable into the view while redirecting!

there is two way for you to do that. first load view inside the create. and second get `$client_id` variable inside the `invoice/create/` route controller. so you can inject your variables into your views when loading theme.

there is one important point. if the view is separated from a controller function then it should load it's own variables independently (inside the functions that load the view). otherwise it should be loaded inside of that controller.